# Recreate copyright information on merged and minified files

Tags: copyright

When a web-application is finished we minify our source and combine all different CSS and JS files into one, to speed up the performance (pageload).

As I thought about it, I recognize that some tools delete all comments (from source) so that you've to  add the copyright information on the correct place afterwards.

So I came to the idea to reformat this information.

Here a example what I mean, default copyright-informations:

```
/*! jQuery v1.11.3 | (c) 2005, 2015 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */ {minfied source code}

/*
 * responsive-carousel ajax include extension
 * https://github.com/filamentgroup/responsive-carousel
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Filament Group, Inc.
 * Licensed under the MIT, GPL licenses.
 */

/*!
    Slimbox v2.05 - The ultimate lightweight Lightbox clone for jQuery
    (c) 2007-2013 Christophe Beyls <http://www.digitalia.be>
    MIT-style license.
*/
```

To something like this:

```
/* 
 * Name         Version    Licence-Type    Licence-URL       Copyright    Copyright-Owner           Source
 *
 * jQuery       1.11.3     MIT             URL-TO-LICENCE    2005-2015    jQuery Foundation, Inc    URL-TO-SOURCE
 * jQuery UI    1.11.4     MIT             URL-TO-LICENCE    2015         jQuery Foundation, Inc    URL-TO-SOURCE
 * Slimbox      2.05       MIT-style       URL-TO-LICENCE    2007-2013    Christophe Beyls          URL-TO-SOURCE
 */
```

But the question is... is that allowd/legal? Or is this already then a copyright/licence-issue? In the licence text I don't found informations about that.

**edited:** URL-TO-Phrases for URLs, because stackexchange identifys doubles as spam.

Comment: I don't understand your question: Are you asking whether it is legal to change the format of a copyright notice?

Comment: Yeah, only the format. I don't want to claim the ownership of the copyright or want to change the the license. Only the way it shown (formated) to the people who look into the code, so they can see all included third party script/pluin names, copyright and license information in a clean table like comment at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no required form for a copyright license (unless it is a requirement of a sup-ordinate license). Go for your life.

Comment: So that sounds it should be no problem, right? Another question, could you give me more hints what a sup-ordinate license is? I never heard about it and want to research about it.